# Getting : FileNotFoundError

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to access a firestore database, it was working well with the provided json file, but now it gives this error: `[Errno 2] No such file or directory`. So any solution for that? Thank you.
This is the code:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

cred = credentials.Certificate('json file')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()
doc_ref = db.collection(u'device-configs').document('5ed7ee5c31ed1b8166e1c2ee')

doc_ref.update({
    u'value.on': True
})
```

```
Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'json file'
  File "/home/lenovo2/Desktop/FYP/Python files/Classes/Deep_Q-learning/firestore_test.py", line 5, in <module>
    cred = credentials.Certificate('json file')
```

Comment: Make sure that the file exists.

Comment: yes it exists in the same place with the python file

Comment: Please show a [mre].

Comment: Please also show the complete error message with traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i can see your path could be wrong. Your current path is this:

```
cred = credentials.Certificate('json file')
```

But it should be the full path like this:

```
cred = credentials.Certificate('C:/Users/Directory/folderName/jsonFile.json')
```

**Pleas also take note of what type of file it is, it must have the file extension too**